# I am trying use the output of a 16-bit encoder as to give input to the register (PIPO)

Tags: verilog, test-bench, iverilog

I am trying use the output of a **16-bit encoder** as to give input to the **register(PIPO)**.
The 16-bit encoder will give 4-bit binary output; these 4-bit binary output will be given as input to the register.

```
`timescale 1ps/1ps

module encoder16to4 (clk,en,encoder_in,encoder_out);

input clk,en;
input [15:0]encoder_in;
output reg [3:0] encoder_out;

always @(*) begin
    if(en)
        case(encoder_in)
        16'b0000000000000001 : encoder_out =4'b0000;
        16'b0000000000000010 : encoder_out =4'b0001;
        16'b0000000000000100 : encoder_out =4'b0010;
        16'b0000000000001000 : encoder_out =4'b0011;
        16'b0000000000010000 : encoder_out =4'b0100;
        16'b0000000000100000 : encoder_out =4'b0101;
        16'b0000000001000000 : encoder_out =4'b0110;
        16'b0000000010000000 : encoder_out =4'b0111;
        16'b0000000100000000 : encoder_out =4'b1000;
        16'b0000001000000000 : encoder_out =4'b1001;
        16'b0000010000000000 : encoder_out =4'b1010;
        16'b0000100000000000 : encoder_out =4'b1011;
        16'b0001000000000000 : encoder_out =4'b1100;
        16'b0010000000000000 : encoder_out =4'b1101;
        16'b0100000000000000 : encoder_out =4'b1110;
        16'b1000000000000000 : encoder_out =4'b1111;
        default: encoder_out = 3'bxxx;
        endcase
    else
        encoder_out= 3'b000;
end
 
endmodule

module PIPO (clk,reset,pipo_in,pipo_out);

input clk;
input reset;
input [3:0] pipo_in;
output reg [3:0] pipo_out;


always @(*) begin
    if (reset)
        pipo_out = 4'b0000;
    else
        pipo_out = pipo_in;
end

endmodule
```

Here is the test bench where i am trying to instantiated the above said

```
module tb;
reg clk;
reg en;
reg reset;
reg [15:0]encoder_in;
reg [3:0]encoder_out;
reg [3:0]pipo_in; 
wire [3:0]pipo_out;

encoder16to4 iencoder16to4(.clk(clk),.en(en),.encoder_in(encoder_in),.encoder_out(pipo_in));

initial begin
clk=0;
forever
#50 clk= ~clk;
end

initial begin
    $monitor("Time=%2t, Clock=%d, en=%b, in=%b, out=%b, pipo_in=%b, pipo_out=%b", $time, clk, en,encoder_in,encoder_out,pipo_in,pipo_out);
    $dumpfile("tb.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0,tb);
        
        clk=1;en=1;encoder_in=16'b0000000000000001;encoder_out =4'b0000;pipo_in=4'b0000;
        clk=1;en=1;encoder_in=16'b0000000000000010;encoder_out =4'b0001;pipo_in=4'b0001;
        clk=1;en=1;encoder_in=16'b0000000000000100;encoder_out =4'b0010;pipo_in=4'b0010;
        clk=1;en=1;encoder_in=16'b0000000000001000;encoder_out =4'b0011;pipo_in=4'b0011;
        clk=1;en=1;encoder_in=16'b0000000000010000;encoder_out =4'b0100;pipo_in=4'b0100;
        clk=1;en=1;encoder_in=16'b0000000000100000;encoder_out =4'b0101;pipo_in=4'b0101;
        
    $finish;
    end  

 
endmodule
```

This is the error I am getting in the terminal.

```
tb.v:12: error: reg pipo_in; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
tb.v:12: error: Output port expression must support continuous assignment.
tb.v:12:      : Port 4 (encoder_out) of encoder16to4 is connected to pipo_in
```

Line 12

```
encoder16to4 iencoder16to4(.clk(clk),.en(en),.encoder_in(encoder_in),.encoder_out(pipo_in));
```

What correction should I do to make it work?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that you must not assign values to `pipo_in` in the testbench because you connected it to a module instance output.  You also must not declare it as a `reg`; change it to a `wire`.

The same is true for the `encoder_out` testbench signal.

You also need to add an instance of the `PIPO` module.

You should not assign to `clk` in the `initial` block since you assign it in the `always` block.

You need to add delays to your inputs;  for example, you can use `posedge clk`:

```
module tb;
reg clk;
reg en;
reg reset;
reg [15:0]encoder_in;
wire [3:0]encoder_out;
wire [3:0]pipo_in; 
wire [3:0]pipo_out;

encoder16to4 iencoder16to4(.clk(clk),.en(en),.encoder_in(encoder_in),.encoder_out(pipo_in));
PIPO PIPO (clk,reset,pipo_in,pipo_out);

initial begin
clk=0;
forever
#50 clk= ~clk;
end

initial begin
    $monitor("Time=%2t, Clock=%d, en=%b, in=%b, out=%b, pipo_in=%b, pipo_out=%b", $time, clk, en,encoder_in,encoder_out,pipo_in,pipo_out);
    $dumpfile("tb.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0,tb);
                
    @(posedge clk) en=1;encoder_in=16'b0000000000000001;
    @(posedge clk) en=1;encoder_in=16'b0000000000000010;
    @(posedge clk) en=1;encoder_in=16'b0000000000000100;
    @(posedge clk) en=1;encoder_in=16'b0000000000001000;
    @(posedge clk) en=1;encoder_in=16'b0000000000010000;
    @(posedge clk) en=1;encoder_in=16'b0000000000100000;
        
    $finish;
end  
 
endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

Please be attention that `multiple drivers of variables is not allowed in verilog`. In your testbench you have multiple driver on `pipo_in`, first in `line 10` when you pass it to `iencoder16to4 instance`, and second one is when you assign value to it in `lines [22-27]`, so you need remove one of these drivers.

You have other mistakes in your code:

1. You do **not** need to re-assign `1 to clk in lines [22-27]`,because you already have clk generator in `lines [12-15]`.
2. In testbench we should **drive the inputs and monitor the outputs**, but note that in your testbench `you also drive the output encoder_out in lines [22-27]` and this is also **consider mistake and you should remove it**.
3. The delays between inputs is missed in your testbench, so you should insert delays between them.